# Tkinter Scale to input values to pandas dataframe.head

Tags: pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to use Tkinter's Scale widget to pass a value to a function that should modify the value of a pandas dataframe.head(). For example, if the Tkinter scale is set to 50, the value passed to the .head method should look like this: dataframe.head(50).

My code looks like this:

```
def scatterplot(value):
    try:
        global graph
        global bar_chart_df
        global clean_df
        global correlation
        correlation = clean_df.groupby(['FACILITY ZIP', 'FACILITY NAME'])['VIOLATION DESCRIPTION'].count().reset_index(name='No. Violations').sort_values(by='No. Violations', ascending=False)
    
        hue = correlation["FACILITY NAME"].head(value)
        y = correlation["FACILITY ZIP"].head(value)
        x = correlation["No. Violations"].head(value)
    
        sns.scatterplot(x, y, hue)
        plt.title('Correlation between the number of violations committed per vendor and their zip code (sample of 150)')
        plt.legend(loc='upper right')
        plt.figure(figsize=(30, 45), dpi=300, facecolor='w', edgecolor='k')
        plt.tight_layout()
        plt.show()
     except:
        my_error = tk.messagebox.showerror(title="Try again", message="Please load a valid dataset")



cmd_frame_3 = ttk.LabelFrame(self.window, text="Statistics", relief=tk.RIDGE)
cmd_frame_3.grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=tk.E + tk.W + tk.N + tk.S, padx=6)
    
my_scale = tk.Scale(entry_frame, from_=0, to=100, command=scatterplot, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, width=8, length=200)
my_scale.grid(row=4, column=2, sticky=tk.W)
```

For some reason, it doesn't work and shows this error:

> correlation = clean_df.groupby(['FACILITY ZIP', 'FACILITY
> NAME'])['VIOLATION DESCRIPTION'].count().reset_index(name='No.
> Violations').sort_values(by='No. Violations', ascending=False)
>
> NameError: name 'clean_df' is not defined
>
> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1883, in
> **call**
> return self.func(*args)

What am I not seeing?

Comment: please provide error message or [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or preferably both

Comment: @will.cass.wrig just added the error